# No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material'

Tags: android, material-design

After reading [this answer](http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/297xli/howto_use_the_v21_support_libs_on_older_versions/), I made [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/preview/material/ui-widgets.html#recyclerview) ran it on Android 3.0+. But `styles.xml` in `values-v21` still causes the error.

**Theme.**

```
<!-- inherit from the material theme -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">

    <!-- Main theme colors -->
    <!-- your app's branding color (for the app bar) -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">#f00</item>
    <!-- darker variant of colorPrimary (for status bar, contextual app bars) -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#0f0</item>
    <!-- theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
    <item name="android:colorAccent">#00f</item>
</style>
```

**Error.**

> Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches
>   the given name 'android:Theme.Material'.

I need to support Android versions from Android 3.0.x (API level 11). `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="L" android:targetSdkVersion="L" />` is not a solution.

Comment: Have two different style.xml file in two different folders. values-V20 and values

Comment: @hoomi, I already have `values` and `values-v21`. `android:Theme.Material` causes the error.

Comment: android:Theme.Material is supported only from API level 20.

Comment: @Ranjith, I think you're right. Please write an answer, and I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`android:Theme.Material` is supported only from API level 21. You can see the error message in android studio as below:

```
android.Theme.Material requires API level 21(current min is 14)
```

Comment: OK, let's use `android.Theme.Material` for small projects to just learn it and hope for a fix from Google

Comment: this means, in Android Studio, that Project -> right click -> Open Module Settings -> under Modules, select your project -> Compile Sdk Version must be API 21

Answer (score 1):

If you use the support library, you can safely use those attributes, and they will work (as much as the OS allows) :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">

    <item name="colorPrimary">...</item>
</style>
```

You can also use the others:

```
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">...</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">...</item>
```