# How to make material navigation bar in android application

Tags: android, eclipse, android-styles

Hi I got this error while make material navigation bar in eclipse

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
         <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    </style>
```

But I got this error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimary'. Already I was installed Android support repository, till I got the error. And I refered some links, but it's not solve my error. Reference [this link not works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25688373/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-androidtheme-material)

Comment: Check your attrs file. colorPrimary may not found in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Used this**

```
parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
```

**Instead of**

```
parent="android:Theme.Light"
```

**requires API level 21**